# Why is this loop in a then callback faster than in an async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

While I was playing with TS for learning purposes, I discovered that a then callback takes less than an async function with await. Here are my code snippets:

**Code with async/await:**

```js
const asyncCodeBlocker = async function(){
    console.log("notAsync")
    await Promise.resolve();
    console.time("async");
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000000) { i++; }
    console.timeEnd("async");
    return 'billion loops done with async';
}

asyncCodeBlocker().then(v => {console.log(v)})

console.log("mainStack")
```

**result:**

```
notAsync
mainStack
async: 2.464s
billion loops done with async
```

**Code with nested promise:**

```js
const promiseCodeBlocker = function(){
    console.log("notAsyncInPromise")
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.time("promise");
        let i = 0;
        while (i < 1000000000) { i++; }
        console.timeEnd("promise");
        return 'billion loops done with nested promise';
    })
}

promiseCodeBlocker().then(v => {console.log(v)})

console.log("mainStack")
```

**result:**

```
notAsyncInPromise
mainStack
promise: 497.627ms
billion loops done with nested promise
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: There is no difference in the code between `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`, so the fact that you used `async` or `then` before executing your test has no impact on the measured time. Run it multiple times for each "demo", you'll get the same timings on average

Comment: @blex I ran them separately and multiple times.. same result every time.  2.464s is noticeable higher than 497.627ms

Comment: This is probably an artefact of slightly different engine implementation (and optimisations) for different function types, e.g. the scope in which `let i` is stored. But as usual, [this microbenchmark is mostly meaningless for actual code](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html).

Comment: I was running this code with Node v14.17.0 . Another thing that I tried was to run the generated JS directly in browser console, and this time the results were the same for both ways

Comment: @agalbenus That's an indication that a more modern v8 version optimises async functions much better. Try using a node release with a more recent v8 engine - v14.17 is still on 6.14.13 whereas node 16.2 already ships 7.13.0.

Comment: fyi I just ran these in my browser and I got results `945ms` for the first and `944ms` for the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code was written in TypeScript but it was edited and overwritten after posting the question by a community member in JS to be able to run the snippets.

It turned out that the behavior was caused by my TS configuration. I had **compiler** option **"target"** set to **es5**. After changing its value to **es6** I managed to obtain the same results for both snippets.

Original code and results:

**Code with async/await:**

```
const asyncCodeBlocker: () => Promise<any> = async function(){
    console.log("notAsync")
    await Promise.resolve();
    console.time("async");
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000000) { i++; }
    console.timeEnd("async");
    return 'billion loops done with async';
}

asyncCodeBlocker().then(v => {console.log(v)})

console.log("mainStack")
```

**result:**

```
notAsync
mainStack
async: 2.464s
billion loops done with async
```

**Code with nested promise:**

```
const promiseCodeBlocker: () => Promise<any> = function(){
    console.log("notAsyncInPromise")
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.time("promise");
        let i = 0;
        while (i < 1000000000) { i++; }
        console.timeEnd("promise");
        return 'billion loops done with nested promise';
    })
}

promiseCodeBlocker().then(v => {console.log(v)})

console.log("mainStack")
```

**result:**

```
notAsyncInPromise
mainStack
promise: 497.627ms
billion loops done with nested promise
```